# frequency counter code error in pic

Tags: pic, c, proteus

Below is my code to count the pulses at RC0 pin of pic16f877A .
I applied a square wave at rc0 to count pulses.
i used TMR0 as 500ms timer and TMR1 as counter .
but the problem is that tmr1 doesn't increment .
Is there any thing which i have missed out in my code.
I used virtual terminal and uart to monitor the values of the TMR0 and TMR1.

```
 int check=1,l,t;
```

uart function

```
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(unsigned i) {
 char puf[6]; //for max 5 digits and the end-sign
 WordToStr(i, puf); // in "Conversions" library
 UART1_Write_Text(puf);
 return i;
 }
```

interrupt routine

```
 void interrupt()
 {
  OPTION_REG=0;
  l=TMR1l;
  t=TMR0;
  INTCON=0;
  T1CON=0x00;
  check=0;
  }
```

init function

```
  void init(){
  OPTION_REG=0;
  T1CON=0;
  INTCON=0;
  ADCON0=0;
  ADCON1 = 0x06;
  CMCON = 0x07;
  TRISC.RC0 = 1;
  PORTC=0;
  }
```

display function

```
   void display(){
   UART1_WRITE_TEXT("TMR0 equal to");
   UART1_Write(13); // newline
   Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(t);    //print timer0 value
   UART1_Write(13); // newline
   UART1_WRITE_TEXT("TMR1L equal to");
   UART1_Write(13); // newline
   Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(l);        //print timer1 value
   UART1_Write(13); // newline
  }
```

main function

```
  void main() {
  UART1_Init(9600);

  init();

  TMR0=193;
  TMR1H=0;
  TMR1l=0;
  INTCON=0xA0;
  OPTION_REG.PSA=0;  // timer0 initialized
  OPTION_REG.PS2=0;
  OPTION_REG.PS1=1;
  OPTION_REG.PS0=0;
  OPTION_REG.T0SE=0;
  OPTION_REG.T0CS=0;
  T1CON=0x07;               //timer1 initialized
  TMR1IE_bit = 0;
  TMR1IF_bit = 0;

   while(check==1){
                             //when timer0 overflows interrupt will make check=0 to come out of the while loop
    }
  display();


   }
```

[image]

Comment: Connect the output of signal generator to DSO and check whether Proteus is actually generating correct signal.

Comment: yes the signal generator works fine @Vagish

Answer (score -1):

Your program do not have while function, which is infinite. Your program ends - this is not good solution. Code for INTCON should be 0x0C (GIE is 7 bit, and PEIE is 6 bit - if we count from 0).
I think here will be more errors. I will check it later.

Comment: intcon will be 0xA0    http://elcodis.com/parts/5904360/PIC16F877A_p26.html this is datasheet for pic16f877A.

Comment: For enabling TMR0, and interrupts: you must set GIE, PEIE, and TMR0IE and TMR1IE. GIE, PEIE and TMR0IE is in INTCON. So you must set: 0b111XXXXX, where X is whatever you want. MSB is GIE, next we see PEIE, and TMR0IE is third. Try this - 0XE0

Comment: i dont think there is any problem with the timer0. It is timer1 which doesnt increment. Nop 0xE0 dint work.

Comment: But PEIE is needed to enable TIM1 INTERRUPT!

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf - 14.11 Interrupts section, see scheme

Comment: but i dint understand why i need interrupt for timer1 . I am using it as a counter . what is the role of interrupt in counters.

Comment: Interrupt is routine which interrupts main program beacuse of another important signal. Interrupt means that THERE IS A SIGNAL. But if you won't do it with interrupt, there will be a problem somewhere in config.